# finding file in the location given only fraction of the file name which is flexible

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a code which looks for the file in the file directory and tells me if its there given only a fraction of the file name.

I have put this fraction i column I8 of the Macro sheet which is a number "121"

The below code works if i manually put the number 121 instead of i, but when  referencing i from the cell it just flags a random excel file in the directory

```
Dim FilePath3 As String
Dim i As String

FilePath3 = Sheets("Macro").Range("J6")
i = Sheets("Macro").Range("I8")

file = Dir$(FilePath3 & "*i*" & ".*")

If (Len(file) > 0) Then
  MsgBox "found " & file
End If
```

Comment: I see that you didn't take the [tour] (click on it), nor accepted any answers on your previous questions, so please take a minute to see how SO community works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is inside of your block of text `"*i*"` , so it isn't the variable `i` that you defined earlier in the code!

Furthermore, you can use `Dir()` inside of a loop like this to see if there is multiple results :

```
Dim FilePath3 As String
Dim i As String

FilePath3 = Sheets("Macro").Range("J6")
i = Sheets("Macro").Range("I8")

file = Dir$(FilePath3 & "*" & i & "*.*")
Do While file <> vbNullString
  If (Len(file) > 0) Then
     MsgBox "found " & file
  End If
  file = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Wonderful, FilePath3 & "*" & i & "*.*"      i should have thought about that, thank you

Comment: @RomanIvanov : Glad I could help! Take a minute to take the [tour] and discover how to accept answers to your question. It is the most important part of SO with upvotes!